# Compare 1st Column in 2 Files and Replace 3rd Column of File 1 with 4th Column of File 2

Tags: text-processing, join

I have a requirement of comparing the first column between 2 pipe delimited files and if they match, I need to replace the 3rd Column in File 1 with 4th Column in File 2.

File 1:

```
111|xyz|23345
222|abc|123
333|xyz|45667
444|xyz|5432
555|xyz|8976
```

File 2:

```
111|xyz|344|rtms
222|abc|222|xyzw
666|xyz|ggg|abde
888|xyz|ff|nnnn
333|xyz|dd|abde
444|xyz|vv|nnnn
555|xyz|bbb|uuyytt
```

Output File:

```
111|xyz|rtms
222|abc|xyzw
333|xyz|abde
444|xyz|nnnn
555|xyz|uuyytt
```

Comment: Search `join` and `awk` tags, it's been beaten to death...

Comment: @Sachin If the below post answered your question, you can mark it as the answer to your question ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One-liner without the need for `awk` and a temporary file:

```
join -t '|' -j1 -o 1.1 1.2 2.4 <(sort -t'|' -k1,1 file1) <(sort -t '|' -k1,1 file2)
```

Using both `join` and `awk`:

First, sort `file2` based on 1st field and save it it `file2.sort`

```
sort -k 1 file2 > file2.sort
```

Now, using "|" as the delimiter, join `file1` and `file2.sort`. Then again using "|" as the delimiter, extract the necessary column using `awk`.

```
join -t '|' file1 file2.sort | awk -F  "|" ' {print $1"|"$2"|"$6}'
```

THe output will be:

```
ron@ron:~$ join -t '|' file1 file2.sort | awk -F  "|" ' {print $1"|"$2"|"$6}'
111|xyz|rtms
222|abc|xyzw
333|xyz|abde
444|xyz|nnnn
555|xyz|uuyytt
```

Comment: Thanks! Even better! @don_crissti But, is `sort -t '|' -k1,1` necessary, works without it too

Comment: Not needed with the given samples, indeed but with unknown input you may need it (e.g. fields with spaces etc) to avoid `join` complaining that input isn't sorted (you're joining using `|` as delimiter but sort by default uses blanks). The first sort isn't needed at all in this particular case as the first file appears to be sorted